# How to extract SQL query from Crystal reports

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports-2008

I want to get the query from the specified crystal report. I have referred the following link...

http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/com.sap.km.cm.docs/oss_notes_boj/sdn_oss_boj_bi/sap%28bD1lbiZjPTAwMQ==%29/bc/bsp/spn/scn_bosap/notes%7B6163636573733d36393736354636443646363436353344333933393338323636393736354637333631373036453646373436353733354636453735364436323635373233443330333033303331333233383330333533313335%7D.do

and tried to do the same with my visual studio 2013. But ended up in some exception. Here is the exception I have received

Interop type 'GroupPathClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.

When I select "show sql query" from database , it shows only the following screen
[image]

Can someone help me to solve this?

Thanking you
Sebastian

Comment: Dont you see show sql query from database menu

Comment: When I click "show sql query" from database menu, the above screen appears.

Comment: Your report is not conbected to database... first connect to any database and then try the option.. according to the window there are no dsn configured in your system..first configure dsm and then connect tk database

Comment: This rpt I have got from my client. All I have this file. I know the database is MySQL. Don't have any other information

Comment: At the minimum you need to know database name and login details to connect to databse from crystal reports... then only you can see sql query

Comment: Have any idea, why the text area for data source name is blank? I want to connect to a MySQL database in a different PC.

Comment: There is no dsn created on your system where crystal reports is run..as I said earlier create a dsn an see this window..you will find dsn name

Comment: Thanks I got it. I got the DB structure from client , I was able to get the report query. Issue solved. Thanks for support.